# Issue with break statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Simple program taking a user inputted year, and determine if that year is a leap year or not. Keeps coming back with an error for the 'break' statement. Maybe I'm missing something stupid. Any ideas?

```
def is_leap(year):
leap = False

# Write your logic here
if ((year / 4) % 2== 0) and ((year / 400) % 2 == 0):
    if ((year / 100) % 2== 0):
        break
    else:
        leap = True
return leap

year = int(input())
```

Comment: Perhaps you would like to fix your indentation. The code you have posted currently does not make sense.

Comment: you can only `break` `for` and `while` loops. did you mean to `return False`? also: `year / 100` (is a `float`) should be `year // 100`.

Comment: What about [reading the documentation ?](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement)

Answer (score 3):

```
def is_leap(year):
 if year%4==0:
    if (year%100==0 and year%400!=0):
        return False
    else:
        return True
 return False

year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Missing returning `False` on `not ((year / 4) % 2== 0) and ((year / 400) % 2 == 0)`

Comment: I think `return 0` should be `return False`.

Answer (score 0):

Your should use `pass` instead of `break`.

`break` is used to stop a loop, not an `if` statement.

See also:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_break_statement.htm
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_pass_statement.htm
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_continue_statement.htm